# Smooth camera stop motion unity3d ios

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, camera

I have been googling for solution to stop camera in motion. But could not find a better solution. I used this [script](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14489) from asset store. it does what it says but stops suddenly when i stop touching the device.
I need help to modify this script to achieve my goal.

Comment: please google "unity3d smooth follow" for many solutions, hope it helps

Comment: yes I know about smooth follow script. But I don't want to follow any player with camera. I want to move camera on touch.

Comment: ok, you probably want to use `MoveTowards` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show me your line of code where you are moving camera? If you are using `transform.position` , try `transform.Translate` instead of using `transform.position`.